# Footnotes in minipages without footnote separator and increased indent

Tags: footnotes, minipage

How do I cancel the footnote separator line in **minipages only**? I would also like to increase the indent of footnotes in minipages only. This is handy after tables, for instance.

Ideally, I would use the `footmisc` package with the `norule` option, but this affects the entire document, and not only the minipage environments.

Answer (score 2):

One solution for canceling the separator is to use the `footmisc` package with the `splitrule` option, and redefine the `\mpfootnoterule` and `\splitfootnoterule` commands as following:

```
\usepackage[splitrule]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\mpfootnoterule}{}
\let\splitfootnoterule\footnoterule
```

But appart from being a quite ugly workaround, it doesn't solve the problem of the indentation.

Answer (score 2):

In `latex.ltx`, the `\footnoterule` is called at the end of the `minipage` environment when there are footnotes. So first I redefine the `\endminipage` command to omit the `\footnoterule`.

In `article.cls`, the indentation is produced by the `\@makefntext` command. This same command is called for both main-text and minipage footnotes. So we have to redefine the `\mpfootnotetext` command so that when it is called, it then redefines `\@makefntext`.

This might be dangerous, but it seems to work. I welcome feedback from those more knowledgable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\mpparindent}
\setlength{\mpparindent}{0.5in}

\let\oldendminipage\endminipage
\def\endminipage{\let\footnoterule\relax\oldendminipage}

\makeatletter
\let\@oldmpfootnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \hspace*{\mpparindent}
        \parindent\mpparindent
        \noindent
        \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
    \@oldmpfootnotetext{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
Table~\ref{table} shows a palindrome.\footnote{You can use it to make a magic square.}

\begin{table}
\caption{Sator arepo}
\label{table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Sator arepo tenet opera rotas.\footnote{This is a palindrome.}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]