# How to remove footnote separator underneath table

Tags: tables, footnotes, footmisc

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
\toprule
A    & B     & C     \\ \midrule
Text & 123   & 123   \\
Text & 123\footnote{An interesting footnote.} & 123 \\
Text & 123   & 123   \\ \midrule
Text & 12345 & 12345 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of MWE.]

I am using the [footmisc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package to insert footnotes in tables. It shows my footnotes under the tables as desired but the usual footnote separator feels redundant following the booktabs style bottom rule.

Is there a way to disable the footnote separator in these cases only while leaving them intact for the rest of the document?

I know `\usepackage[norule]{footmisc}` turns them off altogether, but I only need to remove them underneath tables.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Minimal working example added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
\toprule
A    & B     & C     \\ \midrule
Text & 123   & 123   \\
Text & 123\footnote{An interesting footnote.} & 123 \\
Text & 123   & 123   \\ \midrule
Text & 12345 & 12345 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

test\footnote{An interesting footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Solves it perfectly!

Comment: If you are looking to keep arabic numbering too, just add \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}.

Answer (score 2):

A more automatic solution, not requiring adding code inside each applicable `minipage`.

The `\InFloat` test is borrowed from [How can I detect if I'm inside or outside of a float environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99885/21344)

This renews the `\footnoterule` command after the end of a `tabular` only if it's inside a floating environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\InFloat[2]{\@ifundefined{@captype}{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\InFloat{\renewcommand\footnoterule{}}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
\toprule
A    & B     & C     \\ \midrule
Text & 123   & 123   \\
Text & 123\footnote{An interesting footnote.} & 123 \\
Text & 123   & 123   \\ \midrule
Text & 12345 & 12345 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

Test.\footnote{An interesting footnote.}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Test.\footnote{An interesting footnote.}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to let [`\endminipage` redefine the rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205030/23277).
This does affect all minipages of course but I deem this to be the typical use case anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\let\oldendminipage\endminipage
\def\endminipage{\let\footnoterule\relax\oldendminipage}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrr@{}}
\toprule
A    & B     & C     \\ \midrule
Text & 123   & 123   \\
Text & 123\footnote{An interesting footnote.} & 123 \\
Text & 123   & 123   \\ \midrule
Text & 12345 & 12345 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

Test.\footnote{An interesting footnote.}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Test.\footnote{An interesting footnote.}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```