# How do I make unruled footnotes within an environment?

Tags: environments, footnotes, memoir, rules, scoping

I have a single environment, `fancyfoot`, in which I would like footnotes to have no rules.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{fancyfoot}{
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
}{
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{fancyfoot}
        \lipsum[1]\footnote{First footnote}
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{fancyfoot}
\end{document}
```

I know that although it sound a little funny, it should be feasible to change the properties of `\footnote` by environment scope, e.g. with `\newcommand{\gloss}[1]{{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote{##1}}}`.

Comment: The commands that typeset the footnotes are executed at the time of page shipping --- it can happen anywhere, in your environment or outside. What would you want if in the same page you have the two types of footnotes?

Comment: @Rmanno I don't know, actually. I'd love to see if there is a package that does for footnotes what `amsthm` does for theorems.

Comment: You can do this with footnotes inside a `minipage` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204913/footnotes-in-minipages-without-footnote-separator-and-increased-indent/205030#205030), or inside `table` environments (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226013/how-to-remove-footnote-separator-underneath-table). In both of these cases the footnotes are typeset at the bottom of the environment rather than the bottom of the page.

Comment: @AndrewCashner, I think I probably don't want a `minipage` since this text has to break across pages.

Comment: What will you do if you have a `fancyfoot` environment, with unruled footnotes at the bottom of the page, on the same page as a regular footnote?

Comment: @AndrewCashner, I'd like to assume that that won't happen. I'm just trying to create this particular behavior with minimal side-effects.

Comment: @SimonKuang --- the problem is not well defined. If you just want sometime footnotes without  rules and sometime not, without any fine control, just say `\let\oldf=\footnoterule\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}` when the "no rule zone" start and `\let\footnoterule=\oldf` where it finishes, and cross fingers. Otherwise, you have to define all the corner cases *before* starting to program. The corner cases *will" appear. Ever.

Comment: @Rmano, that is exactly what I am trying to do. Consult my MWE. My question was why this does not work inside an environment.

Comment: @Rmano first comment is really the answer to this question. Add newpage to the body of your environment you'll see.

Comment: @touhami, a `\newpage` between the two paragraphs makes it work, but not a `\newpage` outside the environment. `\AtNextShipout{\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}}` doesn't work either (`everyshi` package).

Comment: the page where `fancyfoot` start will have no rule, the page where `fancyfoot` end will have a rule. So in your example the first page will have a rule if you add new page and `fancyfoot` end in page 2 the first page will have no rule.

Comment: with `everyshi` package you can do this `\let\mtfootnoterule\footnoterule
\newenvironment{fancyfoot}{
\gdef\footnoterule{}
}{\AtNextShipout{\global\let\footnoterule\mtfootnoterule}
}`

Comment: @touhami, I see an answer there.

Comment: @SimonKuang i think it's better if you define a newcommand `\myfootnote{footnote text}` that delete the rule frome the page (next page will have a rule if no `\myfootnote` is used)

Comment: @touhami, that doesn't seem necessary, since this behavior is relevant only at environment scope.

Comment: But @touhami's suggestion is simpler and will achieve the same purpose with somewhat less scope for unexpected oddities. It makes no sense to say that a separate command `doesn't seem necessary` when you are proposing a much more complex solution. It is that added complexity - interfering with the page shipping out etc. which seems unnecessary. Why make it so much more complicated when you'll still have to worry about all the corner cases yourself?